# dynamic view management query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to apply the Table valued function `sys.dm_exec_sql_text()` for [sql_handle] in the below query.

```
SELECT  sql_handle
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats A
```

To me the below 2 queries not working

```
Select  *,sys.dm_exec_sql_text(A.sql_handle)
from    sys.dm_exec_query_stats A 

Error:
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "sys" or the user-defined function or aggregate "sys.dm_exec_sql_text", or the name is ambiguous.

Select  *
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats A,
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(A.sql_handle)

Error:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "A.sql_handle" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can `CROSS APPLY :`

```
...
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats A           
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(A.sql_handle)
```

like the example from microsoft:

```
SELECT TOP 5 total_worker_time/execution_count AS [Avg CPU Time],
    SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,  
        ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
          WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text) 
         ELSE  qs.statement_end_offset
         END  - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
ORDER BY total_worker_time/execution_count DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this for every sql_handle this will create your statements.

```
declare @varbin as varchar(max)
declare @sql2 as varchar(200)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
    FOR select convert(varchar(max),sql_handle,2) from sys.dm_exec_query_stats
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor
into @varbin
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
set @varbin = '0x'+@varbin
set @sql2 = 'sys.dm_exec_sql_text('+@varbin+')'
print @sql2
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor 
INTO @varbin
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```